# Multiple Word Text-Search on MySQL,Returning Number Before Specified Word

Tags: mysql, search, text, full-text-search

I wanna ask, I have a table that contain a column that contain text.For example :
Table name : Table_Books || 
Table Columns : Text, Total_Books, Total_Paper

> Example text in column Text : **146 books were published, 82 books and
>   46 papers were released**

Now,I want to get the number in front of every word books and paper in each row of column Text.

> The result of the query in **Total_Books** will be : **228** (because
>   we find 146 and 82 before word books in column Text) The result of the
>   query in **Total_Paper** will be : **46** (because we find 46 before
>   word papers in column Text)

Can anyone help me how the query is? I dont know how to check if there's more than one books/paper in text of each row.
Thank you so much for the help :D

Comment: This is definitely not a job for mysql.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use php,though. So is it possible to be done by MySQL?
 I've found a way to find the word but only one. 
Can it be done by using function and check the words in text,and if found,then it will be stored into temp_table?
How to check one word per one word in text by using query?